# How to determine if a function or set is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to learn about how to prove whether functions or sets are convex. Unfortunately my teacher uses very hard to understand (for me anyway) notation and I am struggling to get my head around it. I understand that a set is convex if the the line between two points in the set is contained in the set, but are there specific steps to follow or things to check whether or not a function is convex?

-

I have two examples that I am unsure if I am approaching correctly:

(1) Is $x -> (Px,x)^{1/2} $ convex for $P>0?$

This gives $\sqrt{x^TPx}$. So if I take $P=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$
then

$x^tPx$ = $(x_1 x_2)$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}$ = $x_1^2 + x_2^2$

This result will always be positive, therefore for any P > 0, the function will be convex. Is this method a correct way to prove convexity?

(2) Is the following set convex:

${x: ‖x‖_p  ≤1},p=1,2,3 $

I take it as this is the p-norm of $x$ which is the same as writing:

$$(\sum_{i=1}^3 |x_i|^p)^{1/2}$$ where p=1,2,3

So if $f(x)=‖x‖_p$, then f is convex for any p because

$f(x)=‖x‖_p,1≤p< +∞$ (any natural number which includes 1,2 & 3)

$f(0)+(x,y)≤‖x‖_p ‖x‖_q,$  where  $1/p+1/q=1$

$∂f(0)={c(0): ‖c(0)‖_q≤1}$

Where ∂f(v) is the set of all sub-gradients of f at point v (also known as the sub-differential).

Does this make sense? I got this from my lectures but I am a little unsure what it actual means in layman terms

-

Any extra advice or pointers in general about checking whether a set is convex or not would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You prove (1) only for one P, not for any P. For (2) the power should be 1/p. Hint for 1: use the second derivative. Hint for 2: use the definition of a convex set, and use general properties of norms (like the triangle inequality).

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you for your feedback. I am a little unsure how am I to get the second derivative of 3 "unknown" or undefined matrices? That is why I defined P. Is it that $x*x^T$ would give $(x_1^2 +x_2^2)*P$ then you get the second derivative? Would that give 2? Sorry for the confusion, still learning!

Comment: $P$ is fixed, so merely $x$ is unknown. To get the $(i,j)$th element of the Hessian, first take the derivative w.r.t. $x_i$, then to $x_j$.

Comment: @LinAlg Apologies for all the questions but just wanted to check is this how I should be taking the derivative? 

$ df/dx_1$ = $ P_{11} {x_1}_1 {x_2}_1 +P_{12} {x_1}_2 {x_2}_2 + P_{13} {x_1}_1 {x_2}_3 +P_{21} {x_1}_2 {x_2}_ 1+ P_{22} {x_1}_2 {x_2}_2 + P_{23} {x_1}_2 {x_2}_3 + P_{31} {x_1}_3 {x_2}_1 + P_{32} {x_1}_3 {x_2}_2 + P_{33} {x_1}_3 {x_2}_3$

Comment: @LinAlg Also is (2) correct, I changed the power to be $1/p$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) In general, any norm is convex. This follows from 
$\| tx + (1-t)y\| \le t \|x\| + (1-t) \|y\|$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

Note that $x \mapsto \langle Px, x \rangle$ is a norm **iff** $P>0$.

(2) In general, if $f$ is convex, then the set $L = \{ x | f(x) \le C \}$ is
convex. To see this note that if $x,y \in L$, then
$f(tx+(1-t)y) \le t f(x)+(1-t) f(y) \le C$, hence
$tx+(1-t)y \in L$.

Note that the functions $x \mapsto \|x\|_p$ are norms for $p \ge 1$.